# Using bsxfun with an anonymous function

Tags: arrays, matlab, bsxfun

after trying to understand the bsxfun function I have tried to implement it in a script to avoid looping. I am trying to check if each individual element in an array is contained in one matrix, returning a matrix the same size as the initial array containing 1 and 0's respectively. The anonymous function I have created is:

```
myfunction = @(x,y) (sum(any(x == y)));
```

x is the matrix which will contain the 'accepted values' per say. y is the input array. So far I have tried using the bsxfun function in this way:

```
dummyvar = bsxfun(myfunction,dxcp,X)
```

I understand that myfunction is equal to the handle of the anonymous function and that bsxfun can be used to accomplish this I just do not understand the reason for the following error:

```
Non-singleton dimensions of the two input arrays must match each other.
```

I am using the following test data:

```
dxcp = [1 2 3 6 10 20];
X = [2 5 9 18];
```

and hope for the output to be:

```
dummyvar = [1,0,0,0]
```

Cheers, NZBRU.

**EDIT: Reached 15 rep so I have updated the answer**

Comment: I don't understand your expected output `[0,1,1,1]`, can you explain it?

Comment: Hopefully extending @Daniel's question, shouldn't that be [1 0 0 0]?

Comment: Yes that is correct, the output should be [1 0 0 0]. I accidentally mixed that up while typing the question.

Comment: @user3572852 Just do this - `any(bsxfun(@eq,dxcp,X'),2)`?

Comment: Your example makes no sense for `bsxfun()` use and most likely will confuse people who are trying to understand how the function operates. One of the two inputs should be a matrix to be a meaningful example.

Comment: Thanks that works :). Why would you want to transpose X? I do understand that using the logic B = any(A,dim) you would be checking if each row of bsxfun(@eq,dxcp,X' contains nonzero elements. ^I do apologize if my example does not make sense- I am trying to figure out how to use bsxfun() and am in the progress of playing around with it.

Comment: @user3572852 Since `X` is a row vector and so is `dxcp`, if you feed it just like that - `bsxfun(@eq,dxcp,X)`, MATLAB would try to do comparisons element-wise. To make it do comparisons for each element of X against each element of dxcp, you need to make one a column vector and keep another as it is. Finally you would use `any` along the dimension that matches your `bsxfun` output.

Comment: I see now, I have updated the question with what I think to be an explanation to stop confusing others.

Comment: @user3572852 You know you can post your own answer and `SO` encourages it! Read about it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have 15 rep and I have to wait ~8 hours to do so. Seeing as editing it was the next best thing I just did that.

Comment: I don't see why this question has received several downvotes. Anyone care to explain what makes this a bad question?

Comment: @RobertP. That confused me too!

Comment: @user3572852 There you go! Now you can post your edits as an answer! Make sure to remove the edits from your question. Also you can accept your own question.

Comment: Your description that says "y is the initial array" can't be right.  `y` is the formal parameter of the anonymous function, and is a scalar, not an array.  Is it `X` or `dxcp` that is the "initial array"?

Answer (score 4):

Thanks again guys, I thought I would update this as I now understand how the solution provided from Divakar works. This might deter confusion from others who have read my initial question and are confused to how bsxfun() works, I think writing it out helps me understand it better too.

**Note: The following may be incorrect, I have just tried to understand how the function operates by looking at this one case.**

The input into the bsxfun function was dxcp and X transposed. The function handle used was @eq so each element was compared.

```
%%// Given data
dxcp = [1 2 3 6 10 20];
X = [2 5 9 18];
```

The following code:

```
bsxfun(@eq,dxcp,X')
```

compared every value of dxcp, the first input variable, to every row of X'. The following matrix is the output of this:

```
dummyvar =

 0     1     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0
```

The first element was found by comparing 1 and 2 dxcp = [**1** 2 3 6 10 20]; X' = [**2**;5;9;18];

The next along the first row was found by comparing 2 and 2 dxcp = [1 **2** 3 6 10 20]; X' = [**2**;5;9;18];

This was repeated until all of the values of dxcp where compared to the first row of X'. Following this logic, the first element in the second row was calculating using the comparison between: dxcp = [**1** 2 3 6 10 20]; X' = [2;**5**;9;18];

The final solution provided was any(bsxfun(@eq,dxcp,X'),2) which is equivalent to: any(dummyvar,2). http://nf.nci.org.au/facilities/software/Matlab/techdoc/ref/any.html seems to explain the any function in detail well. Basically, say:

```
A = [1,2;0,0;0,1]
```

If the following code is run:

```
result = any(A,2)
```

Then the function any will check if each row contains one or several non-zero elements and return 1 if so. The result of this example would be:

```
result = [1;0;1];
```

Because the second input parameter is equal to 2. If the above line was changed to result = any(A,1) then it would check for each column.

Using this logic,

```
result = any(A,2)
```

was used to obtain the final result.

```
1
0
0
0
```

which if needed could be transposed to equal

```
[1,0,0,0]
```

Performance- After running the following code:

```
tic
dummyvar = ~any(bsxfun(@eq,dxcp,X'),2)' 
toc
```

It was found that the duration was:

```
Elapsed time is 0.000085 seconds.
```

The alternative below:

```
tic
arrayfun(@(el) any(el == dxcp),X)
toc
```

using the arrayfun() function (which applies a function to each element of an array) resulted in a runtime of:

```
Elapsed time is 0.000260 seconds.
```

^The above run times are averages over 5 runs of each meaning that in this case bsxfun() is faster (on average).

Comment: Since you are unsure about some of the things here, would you be okay with some edits? Or I guess you can accept or reject based on the edits?

Comment: Sure, go ahead. It will only help clarify it further.

Comment: I wish I could give +1 more for your efforts to try to understand `bsxfun` and also the benchmarks (though across some varying datasizes would have made the conclusions concrete).

Answer (score 0):

You don't want every combination of elements thrown into your `any(x == y)` test, you want each element from `dxcp` tested to see if it exists in `X`.  So here is the short version, which also needs no transposes.  Vectorization should also be a bit faster than `bsxfun`.

```
arrayfun(@(el) any(el == X), dxcp)
```

The result is

```
ans =

     0     1     0     0     0     0
```

Comment: Think for OP's case, this would work instead - `arrayfun(@(el) any(el == dxcp), X)`

Comment: @Divakar: He said he wanted it to be the same size as the "initial array" and listed `dxcp` first.  Doesn't that make it the "initial array"?  Also he said that X is the matrix of accepted values.

Comment: arrayfun(@(el) any(el == dxcp),X) returns [1,0,0,0].

Comment: @user3572852: yes, that returns one for each of your "accepted values" X that is found in the "initial array".  Isn't that the opposite of what you wanted?

Comment: That is just bad wording on my behalf. I did want the result to be the same length as the X array (making the result [1 0 0 0] if that makes any sense). Although thank you for providing an example on how to use arrayfun(). I can see it coming in handy in the future. I see that for the interpenetrated case by you it is more efficient than using bsxfun().

Comment: @user3572852 Maybe you can benchmark the performances and add it to your answer?