# MATLAB: Efficient (vectorized) way to apply function on two matrices?

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

I have two matrices `X and Y`, both of order `mxn`. I want to create a new matrix O of order `mxm` such that each `i,j th` entry in this new matrix is computed by applying a function to `ith` and `jth` row of `X` and `Y` respectively. In my case `m = 10000` and `n = 500`. I tried using a loop but it takes forever. Is there an efficient way to do it?

I am targeting two functions dot product -- `dot(row_i, row_j)` and `exp(-1*norm(row_i-row_j))`. But I was wondering if there is a general way so that I can plugin any function.

Comment: I have feeling that I can use bsxfun but I do not understand what the arguments will be. I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9813554/apply-function-to-every-pair-of-columns-in-two-matrices-in-matlab  which is close but did not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution #1**

For the first case, it looks like you can simply use matrix multiplication after transposing `Y` -

```
X*Y'
```

If you are dealing with complex numbers -

```
conj(X*ctranspose(Y))
```

**Solution #2**

For the second case, you need to do a little more work. You need to use `bsxfun` with `permute` to re-arrange dimensions and employ the raw form of `norm` calculations and finally `squeeze` to get a 2D array output -

```
squeeze(exp(-1*sqrt(sum(bsxfun(@minus,X,permute(Y,[3 2 1])).^2,2)))
```

If you would like to avoid `squeeze`, you can use two `permute`'s -

```
exp(-1*sqrt(sum(bsxfun(@minus,permute(X,[1 3 2]),permute(Y,[3 1 2])).^2,3)))
```

I would also advise you to look into this problem - [Efficiently compute pairwise squared Euclidean distance in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23911670/3293881).

---

In conclusion, there isn't a common most efficient way that could be employed for every function to `ith` and `jth` row of X. If you are still hell bent on that, you can use [anonymous function handles](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) with `bsxfun`, but I am afraid it won't be the most efficient technique.

Comment: Can you please explain the anonymous function handles part.. sorry I am a newbie to MATLAB. I actually tried defining funcs like dotFun = @(x,y) dot(x,y); and used that in K = bsxfun(@(i,j) (dotFun(X(i,:), X(j,:))), 1:m, (1:m)'); but got error unequal dimension A,B

Comment: Would be interesting to see the speedups you might be getting with these!

Comment: @Divakar I meant `'` was right! Dot product has a conjugate

Comment: @Bob I think this could help you on the anonymous function with bsxfun part - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23310433/using-bsxfun-with-an-anonymous-function . Also, would you be dealing with  complex numbers by any chance?

Comment: Real numbers- not yet. But I guess some one will need that in future someday :)

Comment: @Bob Added for those too! :)

Comment: @LuisMendo Took me sometime to figure that out, but finally it's here! Thank you for the heads up there :) +1 for you too BTW for a good alternative solution!

Answer (score 4):

For the second part, you could also use [`pdist2`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/stats/pdist2.html):

```
result = exp(-pdist2(X,Y));
```

Comment: This precisely solves the second part of the question. Thank!